# How to remove duplicates in a list of structs that do not contain a hashcode

Tags: c#, list, struct, duplicates

I seem to be having some problems in removing duplicates in a list of structs.

Here is an example of the struct:

```
struct item 
{
    String name;
    int index;
    String type;
}
```

I want to make it so that items with the same name, index, and type are removed from the list, and I want to use this same list after it's been cleared of duplicates for other methods, I'm just not completely sure how to do this.

Comment: What problems are you having? As far as I can tell `list = list.Distinct().ToList();` should work.

Comment: Also, this is C#, not Java. Strings are `string`, not `String`.

Comment: Does it have to be a list? Using a HashSet would prevent duplication without any checking on your side. Typically issues like this are best handled by using the appropriate data structure.

Comment: @Jashaszun in C# they resolve to the same thing. Give it a try ;)

Comment: @Jashaszun: string in C# is an alias of .NET type String.

Comment: What do you mean by "structs that do not contain a hashcode"? All objects have an hash code.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `ValueType.GetHashCode` only uses the the struct's first field to calculate the object's hashcode, and ignores the other fields, if any of those fields are a reference type. Since two of your fields are reference types (i.e., strings), then only the first field is used (i.e., `name`).

Which means `new item("a", 1, "b")` will return the same hashcode as `new item("a", 99, "cccc")`.

If the first field cannot be used for calculating an hashcode (e.g., `name` is null), then the *second* field will be used instead. Which means `new item(null, 1, "aaa")` will return the same hashcode as `new item(null, 1, "ccc")`.

You have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make use of all three fields. It's also good practice to make these immutable, since an object's hashcode should not mutate.

As Servy points out, if you cannot alter the source code, implement `IEqualityComparer` and pass an instance of your implementation to `Enumerable.Distinct` or to a `HashSet`.

See Eric Lippert's [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: I understand `ValueType.GetHashCode` only takes the first field's hashcode. But, Why that's a problem? That will make possibly large number of collisions. Other than that anything is there? `Equals` method should work correctly right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `Equals` will work correctly, yes, but most ways to obtain a unique collection of items will resort to using *both* `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. So you need both these methods to take all 3 fields into account.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think that whether or not that leads to more collisions depends on the domain. There are 2^31 possible hashcodes, but a much, *much* larger number of possible strings. If your strings are random enough, then a string alone gives you enough entropy to reduce the chances of collision. Now, since the OPs string represents a name, then yes, I agree, in this case the chance for collision is relatively high. And he won't be making an efficient use of an `HashSet` unless he overrides `GetHashCode`.

Comment: This is also why some authors recommend overriding `GetHashCode` for custom value types (e.g., Bill Wagner in Effective C#)

Comment: Well this descends into silliness... The OP requests a struct that does not contain a hashcode.

Comment: @andleer Kind of impossible, since all instances have to have an hashcode. Good point though, I wonder what he meant by that.

Comment: @dcastro Actually you stumped me a bit. I think that we are in both ways somewhat incorrect. The default implementation of `GetHashCode()` for a value type / struct may indeed be broken but my code still works. The default implementation for `Equals()` correctly functions. So GetHashCode leads to inefficiencies but does not break my code. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx `Distinct()` invokes `Equals` as a secondary test when `GetHashCode` returns matching values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = items.Distinct().ToList();
```

The default implementation for `GetHashCode` isn't ideal (broken?) and all my sample items will product the same result but `Distinct` relies on both `GetHashCode` and the default implementation of `Equals` which functions correctly. This may lead to inefficient code but not broken code.

`Distinct()` builds a `Set` collection using its `Add` and `Find` methods. The `Set` collection is marked `internal` and part of the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
public struct Item
{
    public string Name;
    public int Index;
    public string Type;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item1 = new Item() { Index = 0, Name = "Andy", Type = "O", };
        var item2 = new Item() { Index = 0, Name = "Andy", Type = "X", };
        var item3 = new Item() { Index = 0, Name = "Andy", Type = "X", };
        var items = new[] { item1, item2, item3, };

        Console.WriteLine(item1.GetHashCode());  //-1811508281
        Console.WriteLine(item2.GetHashCode());  //-1811508281
        Console.WriteLine(item3.GetHashCode());  //-1811508281

        Console.WriteLine(item1.Equals(item2));  // false
        Console.WriteLine(item2.Equals(item3));  // true

        var c = items.Distinct().ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(c.Count()); // 2
    }
}
```

Comment: The type does not currently have a sensible `GetHashCode` implementation, so this, as it stands, is not an option.

Comment: @Servy Other than collision is there any other problem if we don't override `GetHashCode`? as `ValueType.GetHashCode` hashes only first field, it can result in larger collision but `Equals` is implemented correctly. So `Distinct` method should work correctly right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel There are no real guarantees about the implementation of the method, in the documentation.  It *specifically* calls out that it is not designed to work correctly when used to create hashes for a hash based data structure.  Even if it might work some of the time, they go out of their way to tell you that you cannot expect it to work.  You should listen to that advice.

Comment: @servy Have you read my update here? I don't believe the lack of sensible `GetHashCode` really matters other than a performance hit.

Comment: @andleer Have you read my last comment here?  The documentation for the method *specifically* says that it's not designed to be used exactly how you're using it.

Comment: My main goal is just to remove duplicates in an unsorted list of structs based on some matching data fields; I'm not completely sure how to do it, but would that be a straight forward implementation?

Comment: @servy I am a bit confused as to which documentation you are referring to... My point is that even if `GetHashCode` is flawed, the `Set` collection used by `Distinct` still checks `Equals` and the default implementation works correctly for a value type. Unless you are implying that `GetHashCode` will return different values for matching items, then I don't see the issue around using `Distinct`? If this last assumption on my part is at issue, then you have a very valid point.

Comment: @andleer I'm beginning to think you're right. A correct implementation of `GetHashCode` only requires that equal objects have equal hash codes. It is not required that different objects have different hash codes. Which means it's entirely possible different objects might have equal hash codes (see the Pigeonhole Principle). As such, the default implementation of `GetHashCode` , albeit inefficient, *does* indeed return equal hash codes for equal objects, and does not need to be overriden.